# Unexpected end of input prelude.js

Tags: gulp, browserify

I am trying to work to replicate a problem I am having adding React to an existing application. Unfortunately, at the moment I am running into a completely different problem simply trying to reproduce the original problem.

The basic structure is a new base module compiled by browserify that is then concatenated with the existing module which bootsraps the application for now.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var reactify = require('reactify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('default', ['browserify', 'concat']);

gulp.task('browserify', function(){
    return browserify({
        entries: ['./src/app.js'],
        transform: [["reactify", {"es6": true}]],
        extensions: ['.jsx'],
        debug: true,
        standalone: 'App'
    }).bundle()
    .pipe(source('browserifyPackage.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./oldSrc'));
})

gulp.task('concat', ['browserify'], function(){
    return gulp.src(['./oldSrc/browserifyPackage.js', './oldSrc/app.js'])
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
})
```

the new module is pretty simple

```
window.React = require('react');

module.exports = {
    TodoSection: require('./todoSection')
}
```

And then the old app looks like this

```
_.extend(App, (function(){
    return { init: function(){
        React.render(new App.TodoSection(), document.getElementById('body'));
    }}
}))

window.addEventListener('load', function() { App.init(); }, false).
```

When I try to use this file though I get an "Unexpected end of line" from within prelude.js in browserify. I don't see an obvious problem, but I am obviously missing something.

The complete example project can be found on [Github](https://github.com/mudetroit/browserify-unexpected-end-of-input/tree/b3c0a21dff0b7415557591b22ff75bad990cd2fb)

Comment: Is it maybe the period at the end of this line? `window.addEventListener('load', function() { App.init(); }, false).`

Comment: yep I wasn't seeing that stupid trailing . if you make it an actual answer I will aceppt it. Stupid mistake but just didn't see it

Comment: You look at something for so long you miss the stupid stuff - sometimes you just need a fresh set of eyes to sanity-check it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is probably the period at the end of this line:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() { App.init(); }, false).
```